# How to return a stream of process updates using Fast API

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a Fast API that upon request, creates a time series of images and returns these as a PNG.

However, if the request is particularly large, the process to retrieve these images can take a long time.

I would therefore like  to be able to update the client with the progress of the image retrieval process. E.g. say I have 10 images to retrieve, I would like a stream of 10 responses .. "1/10 of 10 images retrieved" etc..
And then finally once they have all been retrieved, I would like to return the PNG.

The final goal for this is to update a progress bar on the client side.

Is this possible and what is the best way of doing this?

I looked into using background processes and polling the process, however, I need the file to be returned to the user as part of the response, so that it can be displayed on the client side. Background tasks meant that the image was produced outside of the API call.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)